# should I use ajax to import large csv file to mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, csv

there is a large csv file need to be import to mysql database
there are to ways bellow

1 , upload this csv file  using a php then

```
<?php
$row = 1;
$handle = fopen("test.csv","r");
while ($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) {
    // record rows to to database
}
fclose($handle);
?>
```

this way is easy ,but waiting for a long time

2, upload this csv file using a php 
then use ajax to record each row of the csv and output the ajax feedback

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var row =0;
    $.ajax({
        url:"csv_to_db.php",    //record only one row
        type:"POST",
        data:{
            row : row;
        },
        success:function(){
            row++;
        }
    });
</script>
```

this way can see the active feedback ajax info ,and the browser will not die when the method 1 wait too long time
but this way will excute fgetcsv function in "scv_to_db.php" every time, seems waiting the cpu and memery

Comment: How big is your CSV? I'm currently importing ~30MB csv's with ~25K lines and it works fine (around 10 seconds).

Comment: there should be thousands row in the csv , I don't know yet. you import it in only a php only for one time and only using 10 seconds?

Comment: Upload it and save it in a file, then run a CRON that gets all the CSV files in the folder and imports it. Once imported, delete original file or if you want to keep it move it to another folder.

Comment: As I said, I'm importing 25K lines on a shitty server and it works fine. Your 2nd. option sucks, because you're calling fopen() after every ajax call. You could cache the fopen() result and you should inset rows in a bulk (not 1 by 1)

Comment: thank you , i think i should use method 1 such as what you did